# zoom in on the canvas without changing the resolution in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i would like to have canvas with *28x28(px)* resolution, but make it 'bigger' for the user so he can see/use it.
It will be a canvas for drawing with mouse.

**Is it possible to zoom in on the canvas without changing the resolution in Tkinter?** or should i use a different library?